# Laravel homestead PDOException

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, homestead

So I'm trying to migrate this code:

[image]

[image]

I've 6 migrations like (or similar) this:

**Reaction**

```
class Reaction extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reaction', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('reaction_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('event_id');
            $table->integer('reaction_type');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->timestamp('date');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('reaction');
    }
}
```

**product**

```
class Products extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->bigInteger('pieces');
            $table->timestamp('date_added');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }
}
```

but I've got this error when I type `php artisan migrate`

**Error:**

[image]

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_01_21_134236_users

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`users_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `last_name` varchar(255) not null, `first_name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `statut` int not null, `date_added` timestamp not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists")
      /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post code, and error messages, not images.

Comment: Can you show the migration file contact_event

Comment: You have 3 increment columns in your reaction table. Change `user_id` and `event_id` to be bigInteger instead.

Comment: Check your migration for contact_event table. Make sure there's only one ```$table->increments()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check at the error trace:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create
>   table 'users' ...........

This means that the **users table** already exists so when you run your migrations it is trying to create a table that is already created in your database.

**Note:** Don't forget to backup your database first

Delete **users table** from the database also delete users entries from **migrations table**.

After, To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command:`php artisan migrate`